# Uploading of file is too slow in Webservice in Java

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, file-upload

I have used standard java file stream to upload a file. When I tried to upload a 25MB size zip file , it took almost 11 minutes. but when I tried to upload that file on yousendit.com a file uploading site it just took 25 seconds. Following is my code

```
            File file = new File(destination + fileName);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            InputStream in = dataHandler.getDataSource().getInputStream();
            int len = in.read(buffer);

            while (len != -1) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                len = in.read(buffer);
            }

            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
```

I dont have Ideas ho to speed up the uploading? Is there any other 3rd party API , or any other suggestions?

Comment: possibility is, the uplink of server (hosting the web-service) is slow.

Comment: No our network team has analyzed that , bottleneck is our application that accepts data at that rate.

Comment: you can try Buffered Input/Output Stream

Answer (score 1):

You can split file into chunks and upload each one in separate thread. As far as I remember HTTP standard defines special headers that help server to join the chunks together.

Start from taking a look on [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) from Apcahe

Comment: Thanks Alex , this seems to be good Idea I will try to implement this and will check it I get better results

Answer (score 0):

You may use a flash or html5 plugin to upload the file to your server, and do the things to the file which has been on your server, that'll be much faster I think.

Answer (score 0):

There is something terribly wrong if a software stack cannot achieve 40kb per second throughput on an upload.

I suggest that you increase the size of `buffer`.  Make it 10 times bigger and see if you get a speedup.

If that doesn't help I suggest that you profile your system to try to identify where the bottleneck is.  The code you've written should not be CPU intensive.  If it is, it would be instructive to understand why.

My guess is either that you've got a particularly badly written filter "upstream" of that code ... or that the problem is not in the application at all, despite what the network team thinks.  Perhaps it is a problem with virtualization / virtual networking.